# Encoding for international character

Tags: c#, unicode, character-encoding, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am making a Google suggestion API

And I am requtesting "¿cómo estás" word where it should have return

> ¿cómo estás   ¿cómo estás hoy    ¿cómo estás meaning    ¿cómo estás tú    ¿cómo estás cuando nadas    ¿cómo estás yo (1)   ¿cómo estás yo  ¿cómo  estás response  ¿cómo estás in english

But it is showing

> [{"Phrase":"como estás"},{"Phrase":"cómo estás en
>   inglés"},{"Phrase":"como estás em espanhol"},{"Phrase":"cómo estás
>   lleva acento"},{"Phrase":"cómo estás tú"},{"Phrase":"cómo estás
>   hola"},{"Phrase":"como estas means"},{"Phrase":"como estas
>   reply"},{"Phrase":"como estas usted"},{"Phrase":"como estas hoy"}]

**and response is**

[image]

Ignore the keywords.

You can see the

> ¿

is missing in result

My code is

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Url) as HttpWebRequest;
request.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
using (System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-2"));
    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(result);

if (!ReferenceEquals(doc.Descendants("suggestion"), null) && doc.Descendants("suggestion").Count() > 0)
{
    var suggestions = from suggestion in doc.Descendants("CompleteSuggestion") select new GoogleSuggestion { Phrase = suggestion.Element("suggestion").Attribute("data").Value };
    allSuggestions = suggestions.ToList();
}
```

Please advise which encoding should is use...

Comment: What do the response headers say the encoding is? I'd *expect* it to be UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32 as those are the only encodings RFC 7159 supports. UTF-8 seems the most likely. Of course, it's also possible that there's a problem with the request you sent, which needs to encode the same character - you haven't shown us that.

Comment: @JonSkeet, feeling on the sky, got your attention, I have updated codebase, and response as image...

Comment: Hmm... that's claiming that it's XML though. Are you sure that's the response that actually contains JSON? (As an aside, I don't know whether this is a supported APi at all. If it's the Autosuggest API, I thought that was being withdrawn.)

Comment: I am manually converting it in json.. though when i checked response before converting it is missing "¿" character

Comment: This is google autosuggest "http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=%C2%BFc%C3%B3mo%20est%C3%A1s"

Comment: What do you mean by "I am manually converting it in JSON"? Do you mean the actual response *is* in XML, and you've just shown us the result of your conversion? That wasn't *at all* clear in the question... it seems pointless to show us the JSON when you should have shown us the XML.

Comment: I can see what the URL is - but is there any indication that this is a supported API? I couldn't find it as such with a quick look at the documentation, although I could have missed something.

Comment: I am sorry, did not understand supported API

Comment: And you can see, one character is rendering correctly ony "¿" is missing

Comment: "Supported API" => "One which Google documents that you're supposed and permitted to use" (rather than it just being a URL you've found which might happen to give you what you want)

Comment: As an aside, please pay more attention when formatting your code. I keep fixing it, but then you keep changing the code and posting it with broken indentation again.

Comment: hmmm.... I apologize for that, i will keep it in mind..

Comment: Ok, I will be checking for this having a supported API or not, but as I mention two international character "ó" and "á" is correct there.

Comment: "¿" is being converet "ż"

Comment: I solved it by using " StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));"

Thanks for your patience @jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just if someone could get help..

I solved it by using

```
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
```

Comment: Please accept your answer so that other users know that the question has been answered satisfactorily.